# How to implement pullToRefreshListView using JazzyListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, animation, jazzylistview

I give u some link for hint:

1. https://github.com/twotoasters/jazzylistview
2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample

I already implemented `JazzylistView` but I also want to implement `JazzylistView` with `PullToRefresh` `ListView`. Is this possible? Anyone know this answer , please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this solution. Just copy paste below code in PullToRefreshListView .java file in the library.

```
package com.smartupdater.widget;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.OvershootInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.notecrate.R;
import com.smartupdater.utils.Constants;


public class PullToRefreshListView extends ListView {

    private final JazzyHelper mHelper;
    private static final float PULL_RESISTANCE = 1.7f;
    private static final int BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 700;
    private static final int BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DELAY = 100;
    private static final float BOUNCE_OVERSHOOT_TENSION = 1.4f;
    private static final int ROTATE_ARROW_ANIMATION_DURATION = 250;

    private static enum State {
        PULL_TO_REFRESH, RELEASE_TO_REFRESH, REFRESHING
    }

    /**
     * Interface to implement when you want to get notified of 'pull to refresh'
     * events. Call setOnRefreshListener(..) to activate an OnRefreshListener.
     */
    public interface OnRefreshListener {

        /**
         * Method to be called when a refresh is requested
         */
        public void onRefresh();
    }

    private static int measuredHeaderHeight;

    private boolean scrollbarEnabled;
    private boolean bounceBackHeader;
    private boolean lockScrollWhileRefreshing;
    private boolean showLastUpdatedText;
    private String pullToRefreshText;
    private String releaseToRefreshText;
    private String refreshingText;
    private String lastUpdatedText;
    private SimpleDateFormat lastUpdatedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM HH:mm");

    private float previousY;
    private int headerPadding;
    private boolean hasResetHeader;
    private long lastUpdated = -1;
    private State state;
    private LinearLayout headerContainer;
    private RelativeLayout header;
    private RotateAnimation flipAnimation;
    private RotateAnimation reverseFlipAnimation;
    private ImageView image;
    private ProgressBar spinner;
    private TextView text;
    private TextView lastUpdatedTextView;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener;
    private OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener;

    public PullToRefreshListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHelper = init(context, null);
        init();
    }

    public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mHelper = init(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mHelper = init(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private JazzyHelper init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        JazzyHelper helper = new JazzyHelper(context, attrs);
        super.setOnScrollListener(helper);
        return helper;
    }

    @Override
    public final void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener l) {
        mHelper.setOnScrollListener(l);
    }

    public void setTransitionEffect(int transitionEffect) {
        mHelper.setTransitionEffect(transitionEffect);
    }

    public void setShouldOnlyAnimateNewItems(boolean onlyAnimateNew) {
        mHelper.setShouldOnlyAnimateNewItems(onlyAnimateNew);
    }

    public void setShouldOnlyAnimateFling(boolean onlyFling) {
        mHelper.setShouldOnlyAnimateFling(onlyFling);
    }

    public void setSimulateGridWithList(boolean simulateGridWithList) {
        mHelper.setSimulateGridWithList(simulateGridWithList);
        setClipChildren(!simulateGridWithList);
    }

    public void setMaxAnimationVelocity(int itemsPerSecond) {
        mHelper.setMaxAnimationVelocity(itemsPerSecond);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener) {
        this.onItemLongClickListener = onItemLongClickListener;
    }

    /**
     * Activate an OnRefreshListener to get notified on 'pull to refresh'
     * events.
     * 
     * @param onRefreshListener
     *            The OnRefreshListener to get notified
     */
    public void setOnRefreshListener(OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener) {
        this.onRefreshListener = onRefreshListener;
    }

    /**
     * @return If the list is in 'Refreshing' state
     */
    public boolean isRefreshing() {
        return state == State.REFRESHING;
    }

    /**
     * Default is false. When lockScrollWhileRefreshing is set to true, the list
     * cannot scroll when in 'refreshing' mode. It's 'locked' on refreshing.
     * 
     * @param lockScrollWhileRefreshing
     */
    public void setLockScrollWhileRefreshing(boolean lockScrollWhileRefreshing) {
        this.lockScrollWhileRefreshing = lockScrollWhileRefreshing;
    }

    /**
     * Default is false. Show the last-updated date/time in the 'Pull ro
     * Refresh' header. See 'setLastUpdatedDateFormat' to set the date/time
     * formatting.
     * 
     * @param showLastUpdatedText
     */
    public void setShowLastUpdatedText(boolean showLastUpdatedText) {
        this.showLastUpdatedText = showLastUpdatedText;
        if (!showLastUpdatedText)
            lastUpdatedTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * Default: "dd/MM HH:mm". Set the format in which the last-updated
     * date/time is shown. Meaningless if 'showLastUpdatedText == false
     * (default)'. See 'setShowLastUpdatedText'.
     * 
     * @param lastUpdatedDateFormat
     */
    public void setLastUpdatedDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat lastUpdatedDateFormat) {
        this.lastUpdatedDateFormat = lastUpdatedDateFormat;
    }

    /**
     * Explicitly set the state to refreshing. This is useful when you want to
     * show the spinner and 'Refreshing' text when the refresh was not triggered
     * by 'pull to refresh', for example on start.
     */
    public void setRefreshing() {
        state = State.REFRESHING;
        scrollTo(0, 0);
        setUiRefreshing();
        setHeaderPadding(0);
    }

    /**
     * Set the state back to 'pull to refresh'. Call this method when refreshing
     * the data is finished.
     */
    public void onRefreshComplete() {
        state = State.PULL_TO_REFRESH;
        resetHeader();
        lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Change the label text on state 'Pull to Refresh'
     * 
     * @param pullToRefreshText
     *            Text
     */
    public void setTextPullToRefresh(String pullToRefreshText) {
        this.pullToRefreshText = pullToRefreshText;
        if (state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH) {
            text.setText(pullToRefreshText);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change the label text on state 'Release to Refresh'
     * 
     * @param releaseToRefreshText
     *            Text
     */
    public void setTextReleaseToRefresh(String releaseToRefreshText) {
        this.releaseToRefreshText = releaseToRefreshText;
        if (state == State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH) {
            text.setText(releaseToRefreshText);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change the label text on state 'Refreshing'
     * 
     * @param refreshingText
     *            Text
     */
    public void setTextRefreshing(String refreshingText) {
        this.refreshingText = refreshingText;
        if (state == State.REFRESHING) {
            text.setText(refreshingText);
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

        headerContainer = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_pulldown_header, null);
        header = (RelativeLayout) headerContainer.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_header);
        text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_text);
        lastUpdatedTextView = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_last_updated);
        image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_image);
        spinner = (ProgressBar) header.findViewById(R.id.ptr_id_spinner);

        pullToRefreshText = getContext().getString(R.string.ptr_pull_to_refresh);
        releaseToRefreshText = getContext().getString(R.string.ptr_release_to_refresh);
        refreshingText = getContext().getString(R.string.ptr_refreshing);
        lastUpdatedText = getContext().getString(R.string.ptr_last_updated);

        flipAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, -180, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        flipAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        flipAnimation.setDuration(ROTATE_ARROW_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        flipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        reverseFlipAnimation = new RotateAnimation(-180, 0, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        reverseFlipAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        reverseFlipAnimation.setDuration(ROTATE_ARROW_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        reverseFlipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        addHeaderView(headerContainer);
        setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
        scrollbarEnabled = isVerticalScrollBarEnabled();

        ViewTreeObserver vto = header.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new PTROnGlobalLayoutListener());

        super.setOnItemClickListener(new PTROnItemClickListener());
        super.setOnItemLongClickListener(new PTROnItemLongClickListener());
    }

    private void setHeaderPadding(int padding) {
        headerPadding = padding;
        // Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Header Container=" + headerContainer +
        // " Header=" + header + " Header Padding=" + headerPadding);
        if (header != null) {
            MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) header.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.setMargins(0, Math.round(padding), 0, 0);
            header.setLayoutParams(mlp);
        }
    }                                                                                                     

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (lockScrollWhileRefreshing && (state == State.REFRESHING || getAnimation() != null && !getAnimation().hasEnded())) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)
                previousY = event.getY();
            else
                previousY = -1;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (previousY != -1 && (state == State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH || getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)) {
                switch (state) {
                case RELEASE_TO_REFRESH:
                    setState(State.REFRESHING);
                    bounceBackHeader();

                    break;

                case PULL_TO_REFRESH:
                    resetHeader();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (previousY != -1) {
                float y = event.getY();
                float diff = y - previousY;
                if (diff > 0)
                    diff /= PULL_RESISTANCE;
                previousY = y;

                int newHeaderPadding = Math.max(Math.round(headerPadding + diff), -header.getHeight());

                if (newHeaderPadding != headerPadding && state != State.REFRESHING) {
                    setHeaderPadding(newHeaderPadding);

                    if (state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH && headerPadding > 0) {
                        setState(State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH);

                        image.clearAnimation();
                        image.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
                    } else if (state == State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH && headerPadding < 0) {
                        setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);

                        image.clearAnimation();
                        image.startAnimation(reverseFlipAnimation);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void bounceBackHeader() {
        int yTranslate = state == State.REFRESHING ? header.getHeight() - headerContainer.getHeight() : -headerContainer.getHeight()
                - headerContainer.getTop();

        TranslateAnimation bounceAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, yTranslate);

        bounceAnimation.setDuration(BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        bounceAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        bounceAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
        bounceAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
        bounceAnimation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(BOUNCE_OVERSHOOT_TENSION));
        bounceAnimation.setAnimationListener(new HeaderAnimationListener(yTranslate));

        startAnimation(bounceAnimation);
    }

    private void resetHeader() {
        if (getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0) {
            setHeaderPadding(-header.getHeight());
            setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
            return;
        }

        if (getAnimation() != null && !getAnimation().hasEnded()) {
            bounceBackHeader = true;
        } else {
            bounceBackHeader();
        }
    }

    private void setUiRefreshing() {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.clearAnimation();
        image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        text.setText(refreshingText);
    }

    private void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
        switch (state) {
        case PULL_TO_REFRESH:
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text.setText(pullToRefreshText);

            if (showLastUpdatedText && lastUpdated != -1) {
                lastUpdatedTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lastUpdatedTextView.setText(String.format(lastUpdatedText, lastUpdatedDateFormat.format(new Date(lastUpdated))));
            }

            break;

        case RELEASE_TO_REFRESH:
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text.setText(releaseToRefreshText);
            break;

        case REFRESHING:
            setUiRefreshing();

            lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (onRefreshListener == null) {
                setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
            } else {
                onRefreshListener.onRefresh();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

        if (!hasResetHeader) {
            if (measuredHeaderHeight > 0 && state != State.REFRESHING) {
                setHeaderPadding(-measuredHeaderHeight);
            }

            hasResetHeader = true;
        }
    }

    private class HeaderAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

        private int height, translation;
        private State stateAtAnimationStart;

        public HeaderAnimationListener(int translation) {
            this.translation = translation;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            stateAtAnimationStart = state;

            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
            height = lp.height;
            lp.height = getHeight() - translation;
            setLayoutParams(lp);

            if (scrollbarEnabled) {
                setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            setHeaderPadding(stateAtAnimationStart == State.REFRESHING ? 0 : -measuredHeaderHeight - headerContainer.getTop());
            setSelection(0);

            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = height;
            setLayoutParams(lp);

            if (scrollbarEnabled) {
                setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            }

            if (bounceBackHeader) {
                bounceBackHeader = false;

                postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resetHeader();
                    }
                }, BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DELAY);
            } else if (stateAtAnimationStart != State.REFRESHING) {
                setState(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    }

    private class PTROnGlobalLayoutListener implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int initialHeaderHeight = header.getHeight();

            if (initialHeaderHeight > 0) {
                measuredHeaderHeight = initialHeaderHeight;

                if (measuredHeaderHeight > 0 && state != State.REFRESHING) {
                    setHeaderPadding(-measuredHeaderHeight);
                    requestLayout();
                }
            }

            getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }

    private class PTROnItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            hasResetHeader = false;

            if (onItemClickListener != null && state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH) {
                // Passing up onItemClick. Correct position with the number of
                // header views
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(adapterView, view, position - getHeaderViewsCount(), id);
            }
        }
    }

    private class PTROnItemLongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            hasResetHeader = false;

            if (onItemLongClickListener != null && state == State.PULL_TO_REFRESH) {
                // Passing up onItemLongClick. Correct position with the number
                // of header views
                return onItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(adapterView, view, position - getHeaderViewsCount(), id);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact,you can combine the two frame by modify the source code.
first,modify PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase.java

remove the final,because you have override it in PullToRefreshListView.the purpose is hijack the OnScrollListener,pass it to JazzyHelper.

```
public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
    mOnScrollListener = listener;
}
```

the code in PullToRefreshListView.java.

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2011, 2012 Chris Banes.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *******************************************************************************/
package com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library;

import com.example.jazzydemo.R;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.internal.EmptyViewMethodAccessor;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.internal.LoadingLayout;
import com.xp.lvbh.others.jazzylistview.JazzyEffect;
import com.xp.lvbh.others.jazzylistview.JazzyHelper;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;

public class PullToRefreshListView extends PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase<ListView> {

    private final JazzyHelper mHelper;

    private LoadingLayout mHeaderLoadingView;
    private LoadingLayout mFooterLoadingView;

    private FrameLayout mLvFooterLoadingFrame;

    private boolean mListViewExtrasEnabled;

    public PullToRefreshListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHelper = init(context, null);
    }

    public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mHelper = init(context, null);
    }

    public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, Mode mode) {
        super(context, mode);
        mHelper = init(context, null);
    }

    public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, Mode mode, AnimationStyle style) {
        super(context, mode, style);
        mHelper = init(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public final Orientation getPullToRefreshScrollDirection() {
        return Orientation.VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRefreshing(final boolean doScroll) {
        /**
         * If we're not showing the Refreshing view, or the list is empty, the
         * the header/footer views won't show so we use the normal method.
         */
        ListAdapter adapter = mRefreshableView.getAdapter();
        if (!mListViewExtrasEnabled || !getShowViewWhileRefreshing() || null == adapter || adapter.isEmpty()) {
            super.onRefreshing(doScroll);
            return;
        }

        super.onRefreshing(false);

        final LoadingLayout origLoadingView, listViewLoadingView, oppositeListViewLoadingView;
        final int selection, scrollToY;

        switch (getCurrentMode()) {
            case MANUAL_REFRESH_ONLY:
            case PULL_FROM_END:
                origLoadingView = getFooterLayout();
                listViewLoadingView = mFooterLoadingView;
                oppositeListViewLoadingView = mHeaderLoadingView;
                selection = mRefreshableView.getCount() - 1;
                scrollToY = getScrollY() - getFooterSize();
                break;
            case PULL_FROM_START:
            default:
                origLoadingView = getHeaderLayout();
                listViewLoadingView = mHeaderLoadingView;
                oppositeListViewLoadingView = mFooterLoadingView;
                selection = 0;
                scrollToY = getScrollY() + getHeaderSize();
                break;
        }

        // Hide our original Loading View
        origLoadingView.reset();
        origLoadingView.hideAllViews();

        // Make sure the opposite end is hidden too
        oppositeListViewLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Show the ListView Loading View and set it to refresh.
        listViewLoadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listViewLoadingView.refreshing();

        if (doScroll) {
            // We need to disable the automatic visibility changes for now
            disableLoadingLayoutVisibilityChanges();

            // We scroll slightly so that the ListView's header/footer is at the
            // same Y position as our normal header/footer
            setHeaderScroll(scrollToY);

            // Make sure the ListView is scrolled to show the loading
            // header/footer
            mRefreshableView.setSelection(selection);

            // Smooth scroll as normal
            smoothScrollTo(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        /**
         * If the extras are not enabled, just call up to super and return.
         */
        if (!mListViewExtrasEnabled) {
            super.onReset();
            return;
        }

        final LoadingLayout originalLoadingLayout, listViewLoadingLayout;
        final int scrollToHeight, selection;
        final boolean scrollLvToEdge;

        switch (getCurrentMode()) {
            case MANUAL_REFRESH_ONLY:
            case PULL_FROM_END:
                originalLoadingLayout = getFooterLayout();
                listViewLoadingLayout = mFooterLoadingView;
                selection = mRefreshableView.getCount() - 1;
                scrollToHeight = getFooterSize();
                scrollLvToEdge = Math.abs(mRefreshableView.getLastVisiblePosition() - selection) <= 1;
                break;
            case PULL_FROM_START:
            default:
                originalLoadingLayout = getHeaderLayout();
                listViewLoadingLayout = mHeaderLoadingView;
                scrollToHeight = -getHeaderSize();
                selection = 0;
                scrollLvToEdge = Math.abs(mRefreshableView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - selection) <= 1;
                break;
        }

        // If the ListView header loading layout is showing, then we need to
        // flip so that the original one is showing instead
        if (listViewLoadingLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            // Set our Original View to Visible
            originalLoadingLayout.showInvisibleViews();

            // Hide the ListView Header/Footer
            listViewLoadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            /**
             * Scroll so the View is at the same Y as the ListView
             * header/footer, but only scroll if: we've pulled to refresh, it's
             * positioned correctly
             */
            if (scrollLvToEdge && getState() != State.MANUAL_REFRESHING) {
                mRefreshableView.setSelection(selection);
                setHeaderScroll(scrollToHeight);
            }
        }

        // Finally, call up to super
        super.onReset();
    }

    @Override
    protected LoadingLayoutProxy createLoadingLayoutProxy(final boolean includeStart, final boolean includeEnd) {
        LoadingLayoutProxy proxy = super.createLoadingLayoutProxy(includeStart, includeEnd);

        if (mListViewExtrasEnabled) {
            final Mode mode = getMode();

            if (includeStart && mode.showHeaderLoadingLayout()) {
                proxy.addLayout(mHeaderLoadingView);
            }
            if (includeEnd && mode.showFooterLoadingLayout()) {
                proxy.addLayout(mFooterLoadingView);
            }
        }

        return proxy;
    }

    protected ListView createListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        final ListView lv;
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            lv = new InternalListViewSDK9(context, attrs);
        } else {
            lv = new InternalListView(context, attrs);
        }
        return lv;
    }

    @Override
    protected ListView createRefreshableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        ListView lv = createListView(context, attrs);

        // Set it to this so it can be used in ListActivity/ListFragment
        lv.setId(android.R.id.list);
        return lv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleStyledAttributes(TypedArray a) {
        super.handleStyledAttributes(a);

        mListViewExtrasEnabled = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PullToRefresh_ptrListViewExtrasEnabled, true);

        if (mListViewExtrasEnabled) {
            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            // Create Loading Views ready for use later
            FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(getContext());
            mHeaderLoadingView = createLoadingLayout(getContext(), Mode.PULL_FROM_START, a);
            mHeaderLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            frame.addView(mHeaderLoadingView, lp);
            mRefreshableView.addHeaderView(frame, null, false);

            mLvFooterLoadingFrame = new FrameLayout(getContext());
            mFooterLoadingView = createLoadingLayout(getContext(), Mode.PULL_FROM_END, a);
            mFooterLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mLvFooterLoadingFrame.addView(mFooterLoadingView, lp);

            /**
             * If the value for Scrolling While Refreshing hasn't been
             * explicitly set via XML, enable Scrolling While Refreshing.
             */
            if (!a.hasValue(R.styleable.PullToRefresh_ptrScrollingWhileRefreshingEnabled)) {
                setScrollingWhileRefreshingEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(9)
    final class InternalListViewSDK9 extends InternalListView {

        public InternalListViewSDK9(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX,
                int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {

            final boolean returnValue = super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX,
                    scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, maxOverScrollY, isTouchEvent);

            // Does all of the hard work...
            OverscrollHelper.overScrollBy(PullToRefreshListView.this, deltaX, scrollX, deltaY, scrollY, isTouchEvent);

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    protected class InternalListView extends ListView implements EmptyViewMethodAccessor {

        private boolean mAddedLvFooter = false;

        public InternalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            /**
             * This is a bit hacky, but Samsung's ListView has got a bug in it
             * when using Header/Footer Views and the list is empty. This masks
             * the issue so that it doesn't cause an FC. See Issue #66.
             */
            try {
                super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            /**
             * This is a bit hacky, but Samsung's ListView has got a bug in it
             * when using Header/Footer Views and the list is empty. This masks
             * the issue so that it doesn't cause an FC. See Issue #66.
             */
            try {
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
            // Add the Footer View at the last possible moment
            if (null != mLvFooterLoadingFrame && !mAddedLvFooter) {
                addFooterView(mLvFooterLoadingFrame, null, false);
                mAddedLvFooter = true;
            }

            super.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void setEmptyView(View emptyView) {
            PullToRefreshListView.this.setEmptyView(emptyView);
        }

        @Override
        public void setEmptyViewInternal(View emptyView) {
            super.setEmptyView(emptyView);
        }

    }
    //add jazzy listview
    /**
     * Sets the desired transition effect.
     *
     * @param transitionEffect The non-bundled transition provided by the client.
     */
    public void setTransitionEffect(JazzyEffect transitionEffect) {
        mHelper.setTransitionEffect(transitionEffect);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener l) {
        mHelper.setOnScrollListener(l);
    }

    private JazzyHelper init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        JazzyHelper helper = new JazzyHelper(context, attrs);
        super.setOnScrollListener(helper);
        return helper;
    }
}
```

I hava verify the code.wish can help you.
Here is a demo,you can try it :
https://github.com/XIONGDEYI/PullToRefreshListViewAndJazzyListView